# Uploading image into Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, image

How do I upload an image into GEE?

I would like to

a) just upload an image with no actual geodata just to display in a panel

b) take an image and give it the geodata as well (in QGIS) and upload it.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload GeoTIFFs (or TFRecords, and no other types of imagery) through the code editor:

1. Click on the `Assets` tab on the left-hand-side
2. Click on the big red `New` button
3. Select `GeoTIFF`
4. Follow the instructions in the panel

The documentation got a whole section on this: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_upload

If you need instructions on how to generate a GeoTIFF, submit a separate questions for that.